# Silverlight Polling WCF Method

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Had a question thought someone might have done this before, i have a wcf method that brings back an ienumerable collection of data that is binded to the item source of a datagrid. each record in the db is updated by the windows service regurarly untill the progress is completed, updating counts adding new records etc , each record on the grid reflects each record brought back,  currently the method brings back a list of data where each record is binded to a progress bar control in each row of the grid showing the progress of the work, however this is not live so the user has to press the refresh button each time which makes a wcf call to bring back the updated or new data, here comes my question how can i or whats the easiest and best way to show the progress happening on the control live without a refresh button, so the binding to the control updates and make it seem live?

Thanks in advance